# Enumerate DataTable in chunks

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I have a DataTable thats filling up with 360,000 rows of SQL Data (this is intended).  However this runs into OOM issues.

This is what I have, however, i'm not sure on how to handle everthing after the last interval of 1000.  Or maybe there is a better way

```
int catchInt = 0;
string combineWhereClause = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < ThousandLoopTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    catchInt++;
    combineWhereClause = combineWhereClause + 
                        "','" + 
                         ThousandLoopTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();

    if (catchInt >= 1000)
    {
        catchInt = 0;
        combineWhereClause = combineWhereClause.TrimStart('\'');
        combineWhereClause = combineWhereClause.TrimStart(',');

        Directory.CreateDirectory(ExportDirectory);
        SQLProcessing.SQLProcessor.MasterSqlConnection = 
            SQLProcessing.SQLProcessor.OpenMasterSqlConnection(SQLServer);
        DataTable dtTable = 
            SQLProcessing.SQLProcessor.QueryDataTable(sql_selectionquery);
        for (int m = 0; m < dtTable.Rows.Count; m++)
        {
            string FileName = dtTable.Rows[m].ItemArray[0].ToString() + ".txt";
            string OCR = dtTable.Rows[m].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            File.AppendAllText(ExportDirectory + "\\" + FileName, OCR);

        }

        combineWhereClause = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

So for example if there is 3120 rows, this will do 3000, but will not do the last 120.  However, i'm not sure how to handle the last 120 because I don't really want to do that in the for loop do I?

Comment: I did not, but strongly considered it - your sample code consists of some random custom classes/variables (that likely relate to DB access as they have SQL in names) and some code absolutly not related to querying SQL. There is not much value in it for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to handle data (see other answers), but I think this is what you need for your current approach:

Don't reset `catchInt` for every batch. Instead, initialise it as `1` and let it run as a counter for the whole operation. Then change the `if` to:

```
if (catchInt % 1000 == 0 || catchInt == ThousandLoopTable.Rows.Count)
{
    // Execute your batch
}
```

This uses the [Modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to identify when `catchInt` is divisible by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using LINQ to SQL with [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx)/[Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are simple rules you can follow in order to avoid OutOfMemory exception:

**Never**

1. Work with whole dataset
2. Load whole dataset in memory
3. Execute long-runing transactional code that blocks server side database

**Always**

1. Work with small chunks of data
2. Load small chunk of data (pagination patter)
3. Run non-blocking server code
4. If anything can be done on the server, let it do the work

Make sure your data on the server is not mutable (no one is changing it). If this is not possible to guarantee, you may need to rethink your architecture and use queues and additional tables for processed data.

Comment: the whole dataset cannot fit in memory

Comment: @Mike I probably failed to explain this. It is an antipattern to load whole dataset into memory. What you should do instead is load a small block of that dataset and work on it, save results and discard data. Then load the next block, work on it and so on. Thus at any moment of time you have a small number of records in memory. In LINQ you can use `Skip` and `Take` methods, the same concept exist in other languages/technologies.

Comment: thank you - do you have a link or a how to for these types of patterns?